# MailCore2 MCHTMLCleaner error

Tags: html, ios, c, mailcore2

While using MailCore2, I started getting an error in `MCHTMLCleaner.cc` and method `HTMLCleaner::cleanHTML`. The specific line that is throwing the error is:

`rc = tidySetErrorBuffer(tdoc, &errbuf);`

and the error being printed is:

```
'Assertion failed: (option_defs[ optId ].type == TidyInteger), function SetOptionInt, file ../../src/config.c, line 381'
```

In `config.c` on line 381 is:

`Bool status = ( optId < N_TIDY_OPTIONS );`

Occasionally, this will crash the app, which seems contrary to the entire idea of a try/catch block that would make the most sense here.

More often than not, this code/file will not stop the app and instead just print out an error.

What is causing this to crash? Has anyone else experienced this? IS the HTML actually being cleaned or is nothing being returned for you?

[Here is a link to the specific file in question on GitHub](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/commit/f1d72a4bdb798f7dc735eda05e462c10e52d09b8#diff-e5953cc626822cf45f88025b85f71008R111).

Comment: Does it happen for specific HTML contents?

Comment: Did you find something? I get the same error using Cocoapods Version 0.5.1. Even if i pass an empty String as html content to the mail.

Comment: I did not. We ended up just using the Gmail API and dropped MailCore.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà I opened up an issue on the repo. I'm trying to build a minimal example.